Converting Formula from Excel to Google Sheets - need alternative to INDIRECT function?
I am attempting to convert a model from Excel to Google Sheets that consists of multiple interconnected sheets that lead to a final output used for insurance pricing purposes. I’ve been able to move most of it over; however, the key sticking point is one formula in particular that will not directly translate.

=IF(T2="NA","NA",IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("Entire State "&S2,INDIRECT(S2),0))),"Entire State "&S2,IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("City of
"&D2,INDIRECT(S2),0))),"City of
"&D2,IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(L2,INDIRECT(S2),1,FALSE)),"Remainder of State
"&S2,VLOOKUP(L2,INDIRECT(S2),1,FALSE)))))

The above is used at the end of a sheet that consists of a US zip code file that further references two other columns prior to the formula (columns S and T), with S using a series of functions that add an underscore to a state if it has multiple words, while T is used as a helper to reference states/territories 1-52 that are contained in a different sheet.
The formula is intended to produce one of five different possibilities based on a combination of inputs in the zip code file along with another separate table (‘ListLookup’).
‘NA’
‘Entire State’ + S2 (state_w_space)
‘City of’ + D2 (city)
L2 (county_name)
‘Remainder of State’ + S2 (state_w_space)

The formula returns exactly what I need when used in Excel, but will only return one of two outcomes (‘NA’ or ‘Entire State + S2) when used in Google Sheets, which essentially means that every US state (non-territory) comes back as ‘Entire State’ + S2. I’m at a loss, other than seeing that the INDIRECT function might be different in Google Sheets compared to Excel.
Any suggestions regarding how to solve and rewrite for Google Sheets?

The question deals with troubleshooting a formula but doesn't include any sample data or a worked example. I'm sure that you have a crystal clear understanding of the data and the formula, but this doesn't come across to users in the question. Would you please provide a minimal, reproducible example, including sample data, as well as examples of the various possibilities.
